# Share a Dongle license from Ubuntu to a VirtualBox Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualbox, dongle

I am trying to run a forensic tool in my **Virtual Box Windows 7 32-Bit** virtual OS. My main OS is Ubuntu 12.04LTS. The forensic tool requires a Dongle that is the license to run the tool. How can I connect the USB ports to identify in Windows 7 so the tool can run. Also I do not see the Dongle come up while I am in Ubuntu. I am running Oracle's Virtual Box. I did get a flashdrive's documents to show up in the virtual box already by sharing a folder with Windows 7, but the contents for the flashdrive actually show up in Ubuntu unlike the Dongle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualbox-2-how-to-pass-through-usb-devices-to-guests-on-an-ubuntu-8.10-host (slightly old, but concepts seem to still apply)

and

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31726/mount-usb-devices-in-virtualbox-with-ubuntu/

might help you solve it.